# How to fetch Request headers of a GET request from vbscript file

Tags: vbscript, postman, hp-uft

HI All I am new in handling http requests and am using UFT and vbscript to achieve the below requirement..I am able to send a GET request in Postman and it has a pre-request script which contains below,

```
pm.environment.set("hmacCreationTime", new Date().getTime());
```

and on sending the Get request everytime we get a unique Auth token. Here the value from the pre-request script is passed as a request header.When i try to send get request from UFT(VB script) the request throws "400 bad status" but is working fine in postman with the request headers as below
[image: Request headers in postman]

so i hardcoded the header("timestamp") using setRequestHeader method in my uft script and now i am able to generate the auth token.Please find below code

```
strWebServiceURL =  "https://demo.com/customer/account/v1/auth/getauthtoken"
Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oWinHttp.SetTimeouts 0, 360000, 360000, 360000
    'Open a HTTP connection to a HTTP resource
    oWinHttp.Open "GET", strWebServiceURL, False
    'owin
    oWinHttp.SetRequestHeader "timestamp","1629371122124"
    oWinHttp.SetRequestHeader "clientId","clientId"
    oWinHttp.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent","neoload"
    'oWinHttp.
    'Send a HTTP request to the HTTP server with the header and body info
    oWinHttp.Send   
        
    oWinHttp.WaitForResponse    
    'Get response
    getRestRequest = oWinHttp.ResponseText
     
    Set oWinHttp = Nothing
```

So i guess the timestamp value from the request Headers are required for the GET request to run successfully and is dynamically fetched from the pre-request script.is there a way to fetch the Request header values from the script ,also i tried getAllresponseheaders(but the timestamp header is not fetched )from UFT script or is there any workaround to achieve this or a way to create the timestamp value in vbscript? Any help to this would be really helpful.Thanks in advance

Comment: [Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0w568awd(v=vs.84)) gives the current date and time, you can   [convert it into a Unix Timestamp](https://www.maxvergelli.com/convert-a-datetime-string-to-a-unix-timestamp-in-vbscript-classic-asp/) and add to the header in VBScript. `oWinHttp.SetRequestHeader "timestamp",CStr(DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now))` . I am not sure if that's what  you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Flakes .but the Timestamp from the Postman request  comes in milliseconds and in 13 digits and the dateDiff function returns only in seconds.Is there a way to convert seconds to milliseconds like in the code above? or some way to get the timestamp header value from the script?

Comment: I am  confused about your second question, about getting the header value _from the script_. Which script? In the code shown you are hardcoding the value?

Comment: HMAC creation time is set as environment variables  in Postman .Is there a way to fetch the environment variable present in postman from the UFT script or vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked fine and can be included in library functions (let me know how it goes for you):

- strURLUNPW = "YourWServicesURL,WSUN,WSPW"
- msgbox (WebService_GET("YourWServicesURL,WSUN,WSPW")

  ```
  Public Function WebService_GET(strURLUNPW)
               arrURLUNPW = Split(strURLUNPW,",")
               strPW = arrURLUNPW(2)
               strUN = arrURLUNPW(1)
               strURL = arrURLUNPW(0)
               WebService_GET = ""
               Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
               objXmlHttpMain.open "GET",strURL,False,strUN,strPW
               objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
               objXmlHttpMain.send strJSONToSend
               WebService_GET = objXmlHttpMain.responseText
   End Function
  ```